# Vars become empty through runOnUiThread (Android)

Tags: java, android, variables, console.log, android-runonuithread

I have this code:

```
Log.d("1", String.valueOf(c));

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
     public void run() {
         Log.d("2", String.valueOf(c));
     }
});
```

The problem here is that out of the runOnUiThread: the 1 = [1]

In in the runOnUiThread: the 2 = []

I need to run some code in the runOnUiThread.

Whats happening?

***EDIT:***

The console.log shows this>

```
08-03 14:16:59.728 11039-13685/com.example.ortel.tagnet 1: [1]
08-03 14:16:59.728 11039-13685/com.example.ortel.tagnet 2: []
```

They show 2 different values for the same variable.

Comment: what does it means 1 = [1] and 2 = [] ? Please provide a more clear description of your question. Thanks

Comment: I editted the question.

Comment: The console returns 1 in the console as [1]

Comment: The console returns 2 in the console as [0]

Comment: ok great. Now try to be more specific on who is accessing the `c` variable and what they are doing with it

Comment: Thats not he point. In the function. The value of c is not what it should be!

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine. Post the declaration of `c`.

Comment: C is established in another class.

Comment: as a public static var.

Comment: 1 is ran outside of the ronOnUIThread. C is declared in a class called PublicVars and set a value to in another class.

Comment: It works fine even if it's declared in another class.

Comment: I have no idea then, all i know is that the value isn't being transfered over!

Comment: Plz show all code that set/get c variable.